# stripe CardError (Cannot charge a customer that has no active card)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
def create_charge
 @amount = 500
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: params[:email])
    pay = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => params[:amount],
    :currency =>params[:currency],
    # :source=>params[:token],
    :customer=>customer.id, # obtained with Stripe.js
    :description => "Charge for ")
    send_json_response("Payment","success",{:pay=>pay})
end
```

Am trying to create a customer and charge that customer using Rails and Stripe. The customer is getting created in Stripe, but I keep getting the error Cannot charge a customer that has no active card when trying to do the charge

Answer (score 1):

if you are taking info of card on this time ... first check card is valid or not

```
begin
  @token = Stripe::Token.create(
      :card => {
          :number => params[:card][:card_number],
          :exp_month => params[:card][:exp_month],
          :exp_year => params[:card][:exp_year],
          :cvc => params[:card][:ccv]
      },
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError, Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message and return
rescue
  flash[:notice] = 'Something went wrong! Try Again'  and return
end
```

if customer is connected to your website 
run webhooks of stripe to check if customer has valid card if not then take that customer to update card page ... to update its card before any purchase

check event type where (  "type": "customer.source.updated")
https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types

on update card try to check again card is valid or not